# MaterialUI Styled Box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am using Material UI 5. I want to create a custom box component so that I don't have to keep defining the same sx prop every time I make a box. I also want all the boxes to look the same. I read over the docs and it lead me to this.

```
const StyledBox = styled(Box)({
          type: 'paper',
          borderRadius: 8,
          m: 4,
          alignItems:"center",
          justifyContent:"center",
          padding: 4,
          boxShadow: 12,
          backgroundColor: 'primary.light',
          '&.hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'primary',
            opacity: [0.9,0.8,0.7]
          }
          });
```

The issue is that when I try to use StyledBox it seemingly has no effect? When I manually create the box with sx prop it works fine. But when I wrap with StyledBox I am seeing no box at all. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
return (

          <StyledBox>
            <Stack spacing={1} sx={{width: 300}}>
            <Typography variant='h3' component='h3'>
              Modem Configuration   
            </Typography>
            <FormLabel>Tx Power Enable</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup
            row
            defaultValue="On">
                <FormControlLabel value="On" control={<Radio />} label="On" />
                <FormControlLabel value="Off" control={<Radio />} label="Off" />
            </RadioGroup>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
            <FormLabel>Tx AGC Power</FormLabel>
            <Select
              value={TxAgcPower}
              onChange={changeTxAgcPower}
            >
              <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            <FormLabel>Tx AGC Enable</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup
            row
            defaultValue="On">
                <FormControlLabel value="On" control={<Radio />} label="On" />
                <FormControlLabel value="Off" control={<Radio />} label="Off" />
            </RadioGroup>
            <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Modem Tx Gain" variant="filled" />
            <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Tx Frequency" variant="filled" />
            <TextField id="filled-basic" label="Rx Frequency" variant="filled" />
            </FormControl>
            <FormLabel>Rx Gain Adjust</FormLabel>
            <Select
              value={RxGainAdj}
              onChange={changeRxGainAdj}
            >
              <MenuItem value={'low'}>Low</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={'high'}>High</MenuItem>
              </Select>
          <Button variant="contained">Apply</Button>
          </Stack>
        </StyledBox>
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I' ve fixed you code if you want to use the solution closer to your initial code (look the `StyledBox`, also `boxShadow` and `hover` were wrong in your code). Also i provided another way if you want to write styled component which is closer to the way you write css (`StyledBox2`).

Also here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boxsx-demo-material-ui-forked-nwgjxz?file=/demo.tsx) to play with the css.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const StyledBox = styled(Box)({
  type: "paper",
  borderRadius: 8,
  m: 4,
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  padding: 4,
  backgroundColor: "#cecece",
  width: "300px",
  height: "300px",
  boxShadow: "1px 1px 5px 0px green",
  transition: "all 0.2s ease",
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7]
  }
});

const StyledBox2 = styled(Box)`
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px green;
  background-color: #cecece;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  &:hover {
    background: red;
  }
`;

export default function BoxSx() {
  return (
    <>
      <StyledBox />
      <StyledBox2 />
    </>
  );
}
```